# Best way to open image?

Tags: python, google-mirror-api

How can I open an image attachment being shared with PIL?

This gave me a "Unauthorized" response

```
Image.open(attachment['contentUrl'])
```

`MediaIoBaseUpload` doesn't have a read method

so `Image.open(media)` won't work either

What's my best option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

I used `io.BytesIO` with the bytes returned from `mirror_service._http.request(attachment['contentUrl'])`

I was able to open that with `Image.open`

Comment: I did the same but with a StringIO.